# Excel VBA - Find and Replace from External File

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a file that I would like to run a Find and Replace on using data from another Excel file.

I have this so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
Sub LegalName()
    Dim NameListWB As Workbook
    Dim NameListWS As Worksheet
    Set NameListWB = Workbooks.Open("File.xlsx")
    Set NameListWS = NameListWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = NameListWS.Range("A:B").Select
     Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("F").Replace _
            What:=ActiveCell.Value, Replacement:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code example posted? Does it throw an error? If so on which line?

Comment: It looks like you're swapping columns?  Could you explain what it is doing when you run it, or are you getting an error?

Comment: Where are you replacing and from where?

Comment: I am searching Column F to see if it has any words that match anything in File.xlsx column A, if it matches I wanted to replace the words with what is in column B of File.xlsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you started by declaring your objects but missed out on few. Also, you need to avoid the use of `.Select` [Interesting Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim NameListWB As Workbook, thisWb As Workbook
    Dim NameListWS As Worksheet, thisWs As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long

    '~~> This is the workbook from where your code is running
    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Change this to the sheet name where you want to replace
    '~~> in Column F
    Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> File.xlsx
    Set NameListWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\File.xlsx")
    Set NameListWS = NameListWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With NameListWS
        '~~> Find last row in Col A of File.xlsx
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop though Col A
        For i = 1 To lRow
            '~~> Do the replace
            thisWs.Columns(6).Replace What:=.Range("A" & i).Value, _
                                      Replacement:=.Range("B" & i).Value, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                      MatchCase:=False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! It seems I have a lot more to lean in VBA but this does work perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: I am adding this to the PERSONAL.XLSB and it is giving me an error for referencing the sheets by there name. I replaced 'Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets("Sheet1")' with 'Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets(1)' as well as the reference below. It does not give me an error any more but it does not work.